# logback appenders fail for scope= "context" but not scope= "system"

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am trying out externalization of `logback-spring.xml` for my Springboot app.
The `logback-spring.xml` file appends logs to two appenders, file appender and logstash appender.

This file includes the externalized `logback-external.yml` file. Both the `logback-spring.xml` and the included file logback-external.yml are scanned for changes periodically as shown below.

A few of the variables which are application specific are fetched from `application.yml` through `<springProperty>`.
For `scope = “context”` or `scope= “local”` or `scope= “system”` the `<springProperty>` variables come as `‘logstash_port_IS_UNDEFINED’` (see logs snapshot) and all the appenders fail.

However, for `scope= “system”` there is a catch. As mentioned in the logback [doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes), *“property with system scope is inserted into the JVM's system properties and lasts as long as the JVM or until it is cleared”*, it seems that the logback appenders continue to work with the old working values for these variables.

Anybody else who has tried fetching application-specific logging parameters into logback-spring.xml file through  and faced a smilar issue while having auto scan enabled? Can I bank on scope= “system” for implementing externalization and auto-scanning of logback?

**logback-spring.xml**

```
 <configuration  debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="15 seconds">
    <property resource="application.yml" />
    <springProperty scope="system" name="logstash_host"
        source="myapp.logging.logstash.host" />
    <springProperty scope="system" name="logstash_port"
        source="myapp.logging.logstash.port" />
    <springProperty scope="system" name="base_log_dir"
        source="base_log" />
    <springProperty  scope="system" name="app_name"
        source="spring.application.name" />
    <springProperty  scope="system" name="app_port"
        source="server.port"/>
    <springProperty scope="system" name="max_history"
        source="logback.max_history_size" />
    <springProperty scope="system" name="max_log_file_size"
        source="max_log_size" />
    
    <include optional="false"
        file="external-logback-file-location/logback-external.xml" />
</configuration>
```

**logback-external.yml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<included>
     
    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING-ALL"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
                <marker>metrics</marker>
            </evaluator>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${base_log_dir}/${app_name}/${app_name}_-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${max_log_file_size}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${max_history}</maxHistory>
            <!---other rolling specific policies here ---->
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level
                %logger{36}.%M [%line] - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<appender name="LOGSTASH"
        class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>${logstash_host}:${logstash_port}</destination>
        <encoder charset="UTF-8"
            class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">           
            <customFields>
            {               
                    "custom-field":"custom-field-value"
            }
            </customFields>
        </encoder>
</appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING-ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH" />
    </root>
    <!-- in the absence of the class attribute, assume ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DefaultShutdownHook -->
    <shutdownHook
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook" />

</included>
```

**Error Logs From Logback**

```
22:37:02,388 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@4c9c7665 - Failed to invoke valueOf{} method in class [ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] with value [max_log_file_size_IS_UNDEFINED]
22:37:02,388 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@4c9c7665 - Failed to set property [maxFileSize] to value "max_log_file_size_IS_UNDEFINED".  ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetterException: Conversion to type [class ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] failed.
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetterException: Conversion to type [class ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] failed.
    
    22:37:02,389 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@99ee192 - Failed to set property [maxHistory] to value "max_history_IS_UNDEFINED".  ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetterException: Conversion to type [int] failed. 
    
    22:37:02,391 |-ERROR in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@945654245 - maxFileSize property is mandatory.
    
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destination 'logstash_host_IS_UNDEFINED:logstash_port_IS_UNDEFINED': unparseable value (expected format 'host[:port]').
    at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.destination.DestinationParser.parse(DestinationParser.java:62)
    at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.addDestination(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:892)
    at  ... 23 common frames omitted
22:37:02,395 |-ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - No destination was configured. Use <destination> to add one or more destinations to the appender
```

Comment: please provide spring-boot version

Comment: @neo 2.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: and please provide the whole error, can't get the root cause from what you provide

Comment: why you need this `springProperty`  tag

Comment: @neo i need it neo for my logging appender to logstash. there are other properties too which work fine when the scope is context

Comment: sorry,busy doing my work.does your code run on your local machine,i think something goes wrong in class `org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringPropertyAction`,u could debug this class line by line to see what's going on and how the `java.lang.NullPointerException` comes out

Comment: On rare occasions we need to change the scope property. can i  have a look at your whole `logback-spring.xml` file

Comment: i added the logback file

Comment: coming again.U said you have read the logback doc, Do u understand  the meaning of `scope= “system”`,you need it only when some variables must be fetched from `jvm system properties`, but in your case , it's in the same logback context,so `scope="context"` is the right thing.`application.yml` file is automatically loaded in spring boot application,and it's also available in logback context  ,u don't need to load it  explicit. what you need to do is checking whether you have set the corresponding properites in your `application.yml` file.

Comment: @neo In my case, since I am implementing externalization+scan, there are some properties fetched from app yml for app specifiic logging (same externalized file would be used by multiple apps). Now, if I chose to keep scope ="context" for app specific variables in logback then next scan finds these variables undefined. But if I keep scope="system" then though these values are again undefined yet logback defaults to the old values for these variables and the appenders work.

Comment: There is in where the doubt crops up : that I am hoodwinking the logback to believe that these are system level variables and won't change; whereas the variables made scope="system" are actually app specific variables that I use for deciding the folder under which logs world create and file-naming-pattern: /root/app-name/app-name-date-i.log.

Comment: The idea is to have a common logback-external.yml file for multiple web-apps while each web-app has their own logback-spring.xml from wherein logback-external.yml is being included. And with scan enabled, for any variable on context scope the value becomes UNDEFINED post the next scan

Comment: Did u try declaring the same property twice with different `scope` value